# How to call the datatable fill code without double in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datatable, oledb, oledbdataadapter

How to call the datatable fill code without double in vb.net?.
in the code below you might see I wrote back the fill datatable code if there is a solution without me writing it back in "GenerateReport()". Please Recommend.

Thanks

```
Private WithEvents dt As New DataTable
 Public Sub fillDataGridView1()
            dt = New DataTable
            Dim query As String = "SELECT NOD,ITM,CIA,DPR,QTY FROM RSD WHERE QTY > 0 AND PNM=@PNM"
            Using con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(GetConnectionString)
                Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(query, con)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PNM", ComboBox1.SelectedValue)
                    Using da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
                        da.Fill(dt)
                        da.Dispose()
                        Dim totalColumn As New DataColumn()
                        totalColumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Double")
                        totalColumn.ColumnName = "Total"
                        totalColumn.Expression = "[CIA]*[QTY]*(1-[DPR]/100)"
                        dt.Columns.Add(totalColumn)
                        Me.grid.DataSource = dt
                        Me.grid.Refresh()
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
End Sub
Private Sub GenerateReport()
KtReport1.Clear()
'the code below actually already exists but I reuse it
dt = New DataTable
            Dim query As String = "SELECT NOD,ITM,CIA,DPR,QTY FROM RSD WHERE QTY > 0 AND PNM=@PNM"
            Using con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(GetConnectionString)
                Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(query, con)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PNM", ComboBox1.SelectedValue)
                    Using da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
                        da.Fill(dt)
Dim dtCloned As DataTable = dt.Clone()
dtCloned.Columns("CIA").DataType = GetType(String)
For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
                            dtCloned.ImportRow(row)
                        Next row
KtReport1.AddDataTable(dtCloned)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are essentially duplicating code despite the fact that you have a variable setup to hold the filled DataTable at the Form level.

What I would suggest doing is creating a function that returns the filled DataTable, then at the top of your two existing methods do a null check against the Form level variable.

Take a look at this example:

```vb
Private _dt As DataTable

Private Function GetAndFillDataTable() As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Dim query As String = "SELECT NOD,ITM,CIA,DPR,QTY FROM RSD WHERE QTY > 0 AND PNM=@PNM"
    Using con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(GetConnectionString)
        Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(query, con)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PNM", ComboBox1.SelectedValue)
            Using da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
                da.Fill(dt)
                da.Dispose()
                Dim totalColumn As New DataColumn()
                totalColumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Double")
                totalColumn.ColumnName = "Total"
                totalColumn.Expression = "[CIA]*[QTY]*(1-[DPR]/100)"
                dt.Columns.Add(totalColumn)
                Return dt
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Function

Private Sub FillDataGridView1()
    If (_dt Is Nothing) Then
        _dt = GetAndFillDataTable()
    End If
    grid.DataSource = _dt
    grid.Refresh()
End Sub

Private Sub GenerateReport()
    If (_dt Is Nothing) Then
        _dt = GetAndFillDataTable()
    End If
    Dim dtCloned As DataTable = _dt.Clone()
    dtCloned.Columns("CIA").DataType = GetType(String)
    For Each row In _dt.Rows
        dtCloned.ImportRow(row)
    Next row
    KtReport1.AddDataTable(dtCloned)
End Sub
```

Comment: sorry I replied late, thank you for your answer but I have an error `Error BC30451 'dt' is not declared` .`Private WithEvents dt As New DataTable` if I use the variable code then there is an error `Error BC31061 variable '_dt' conflicts with a member implicitly declared for WithEvents variable 'dt' in class`

Comment: @And - it looks like I forgot to update the variable name in `GetAndFillDataTable`. I'll update my answer to reflect the correct name.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry I was late replying. But I have a problem with the population in combobox with the function of you, I will make a new post hopefully you can help me

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75229697/combobox-population-does-not-appear-in-datagridview-in-vb-net) here's the latest post link maybe you can help me