# Combobox population does not appear in DataGridView in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datatable, combobox, oledb, oledbdataadapter

Combobox population does not appear in DataGridView because of the function of DataTable.
below link the previous code running normally with the combobox population.
please recommend the best solution.
I have also coded in my post so it doesn't miss communication
Thanks

[link previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75146809/how-to-call-the-datatable-fill-code-without-double-in-vb-net/75147957?noredirect=1#comment132632655_75147957)

```
Private _dt As DataTable
'update code PopulateComboBox in form load
  Public Sub New()
            If Me.IsInDesignMode() Then
                Return
            End If
            InitializeComponent()
            Me.PopulateComboBox()
            fillDataGridView1()
        End Sub
Private Function GetAndFillDataTable() As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Dim query As String = "SELECT NOD,ITM,CIA,DPR,QTY FROM RSD WHERE QTY > 0 AND PNM=@PNM"
    Using con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(GetConnectionString)
        Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(query, con)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PNM", ComboBox1.SelectedValue)
            Using da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
                da.Fill(dt)
                da.Dispose()
                Dim totalColumn As New DataColumn()
                totalColumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Double")
                totalColumn.ColumnName = "Total"
                totalColumn.Expression = "[CIA]*[QTY]*(1-[DPR]/100)"
                dt.Columns.Add(totalColumn)
                Return dt
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Function

Private Sub FillDataGridView1()
    If (_dt Is Nothing) Then
        _dt = GetAndFillDataTable()
    End If
    grid.DataSource = _dt
    grid.Refresh()
End Sub
Private Sub PopulateComboBox()
Dim dt As New DataTable()
 Dim query As String = "SELECT DISTINCT PNM FROM RSD UNION SELECT DISTINCT PNM FROM RSG ORDER BY PNM"
            Try
                dt = New DataTable
                Using con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(GetConnectionString)
                    Using sda As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(query, con)
sda.Fill(dt)
Dim row As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
 row(0) = ""
dt.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0)
  ComboBox1.DataSource = dt
                        ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "PNM"
                        ComboBox1.ValueMember = "PNM"
 End Using
                End Using
            Catch myerror As OleDbException
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " & myerror.Message)
            Finally
            End Try
'update code combobox selectionchangecommited for fillDataGridView1
 Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectionChangeCommitted
fillDataGridView1()
 End Sub
```

Comment: I don't really know what you're saying. Please explain EXACTLY where and how the behaviour of that code differs from your expectations. You need to have debugged the code to see the specific behaviour of each line, not just watched the UI while the app runs.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting your datasource = _dt in PopulateComboBox however the data table you built in your function is called dt.

Comment: Doesn't look like it. `_dt` is used as the datya source for the grid in `FillDataGridView1` while `dt` is used as the data source for the `ComboBox` in `PopulateComboBox`. Of course, the code is poorly written so it's hard to read and easy to make such mistakes.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding the question, the combobox is failing to be populated. Being bound to the wrong data table could certainly be the cause, no? There may be a console error indicating no key/column match.

Comment: That would be a problem, yes, but there's no specific evidence that it is the problem here. You said *"You are setting your datasource = _dt in PopulateComboBox"* but that's not true. `grid.DataSource = _dt` in in `FillDataGridView1` while `ComboBox1.DataSource = dt` is in `PopulateComboBox`.

Comment: @ClearlyClueless , Thank you for your answer. but I used the code as follows `ComboBox1.DataSource = dt` This causes it not to appear in DataGridView. Previously I typed the wrong code in this post `ComboBox1.DataSource = dt` So that there is a miss communication. so what is the solution so that I can solve the datatable problem

Comment: @jmcilhinney apologies, it was late and I was on a phone. Must have misread there. OP, how are you calling the PopulateComboBox Sub? Are you doing so inside of rowdatabound? Can you share the markup for your grid that the combobox is inside of on your OP?

Comment: @ClearlyClueless , `how are you calling the PopulateComboBox Sub?` I use this code
`Public Sub New()  If Me.IsInDesignMode() Then  Return End If InitializeComponent() Me.PopulateComboBox() fillDataGridView1()` and then I use `Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted` for fillDataGridView1()

Comment: Please edit your original post to include the markup for the grid that the combo box is inside as well as the code that calls the sub to populate the combobox.

Comment: @ClearlyClueless , I've updated the code in the post